# Making a clever pattern with GNU SED

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

This is the source string:

```
%5B++The+transmission+is+%5B150mhz%5D+The+year+is+%282017%29+This+is+%2A+great+%2A+so+far++%5D
```

- Is it possible to make a pattern only with **GNU SED** to:

  1. Replace a singe + to a single space
  2. From `%**abc` to `"\x**"abc` (the first two characters after the % is always hex UTF-8)
  3. Every sentence must have one " at the beginning and one " at end of the sentence

So the result to be like this:

```
"\x5B"  "The" "transmission" "is" "\x5B"150mhz"\x5D" "The" "year" "is" "\x28"2017"\x29" "This" "is" "\x2A" "great" "\x2A" "so" "far"  "\x5D"
```

So when echo is used with the string:

```
echo -e "\x5B"  "The" "transmission" "is" "\x5B"150mhz"\x5D" "The" "year" "is" "\x28"2017"\x29" "This" "is" "\x2A" "great" "\x2A" "so" "far"  "\x5D"
```

Will result exactly like this:

```
[ The transmission is [150mhz] The year is (2017) This is * great * so far ]
```

Comment: Can't you just URL-decode the string using Python, etc.?

Comment: I know only the basics of sed and i will like to learn more

Comment: And yet you haven't demonstrated any effort at all.

Comment: I tried i failed i will like to learn from someone that knows SED and his techniques

Comment: Then show us your attempt.

Comment: To learn you show your attempt then you get corrected and your errors and success is highlighted, that's how you learn!

Comment: I don't think you can get `(2017)` from your input string since it has `%28` (or `0x28 left parenthesis`) on both sides

Comment: @wjandrea exacly

Comment: @ steeldriver You are right i corrected my question

Comment: @muru The link you sent me is not the same read my question please.

Comment: Why not? There's a sed solution there, learn from it.

Comment: Like i said in the first place GNU SED  the link you send me has  mixed commands with sed and other programs like awk and etc next time please take more that 5 sec to read a posted question

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
sed -r -e 's/(.*)/"\1"/' -e 's/\+/" "/g' -e 's/""/ /g' -e 's/\%/\\x/g' -e 's/("\\x.{2})/\1"/g' -e 's/""\s+/" /g' -e 's/"(.*)"/"\1/' -e 's/([^"]|(([0-9]|[a-z])))(\\x[0-9]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]))" /\1"\4" /g' src.txt
```

Result:

```
"\x5B"  "The" "transmission" "is" "\x5B"150mhz"\x5D" "The" "year" "is" "\x28"2017"\x29" "This" "is" "\x2A" "great" "\x2A" "so" "far"  "\x5D"
```

Then on:

```
echo -e "\x5B"  "The" "transmission" "is" "\x5B"150mhz"\x5D" "The" "year" "is" "\x28"2017"\x29" "This" "is" "\x2A" "great" "\x2A" "so" "far"  "\x5D"
```

Result:

```
[ The transmission is [150mhz] The year is (2017) This is * great * so far ]
```

I don't think the `sed` is the best tool to use here but since your looking to learn .

Comment: Thank you can be something like this? echo "%2A+Hello" | sed -e 's/%/"\\/g' -e '/"\\/s/+/" /g'

Comment: Still working on it when done will update this

Comment: echo "%5B++The+transmission+is+%5B150mhz%5D+The+year+is+%282017%29+This+is+%2A+great+%2A+so+far++%5D" | sed -re 's/\+/ /g' -e 's/\%/\\x/g' -e 's/\s+/" "/g' is missing two " in "\x5B150mhz\x5D"  and "\x282017\x29" one " to the  end

Comment: yes will fix that!

Comment: :  ) just telling

Comment: @GoldHaloWings it's done see my updated answer but I feel the `dup` link would have been a better option, but if `sed` is required then my answer should help. Quite a challenge I tell you but glad I pulled through.

Comment: Thank very much George i appreciate your help and as i can see it was quite a challenge indeed

Comment: sed -e 's/\+/ /g' -e 's/\%/\\x/g' -e 's/\\.../&"/g' -e 's/\\/"\\/g' this is more smaller with the same result sorry for the many comments

Comment: Yes but I believe you desired the result to look like this `"\x5B"  "The" "transmission" "is" "\x5B"150mhz"\x5D" "The" "year" "is" "\x28"2017"\x29" "This" "is" "\x2A" "great" "\x2A" "so" "far"  "\x5D"`. I had a similar short regex but had to modify t make the result come out as you stated in your question. I usually don't second guess the intention of the owner of the question but use what is provided to answer the question. If that is okay then go ahead and use that version!

Comment: Stupid of me, you are right it seems than i can't beat your pattern the best answer is still yours